# Display real-time filtering data from another worksheet in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I want to display all rows that have a "Gender" column equal to "M" inside "sheet2", where the data is retrieved from "sheet1". The filtered data also has to be real time, meaning whenever I make a change in the Gender column in "sheet1", "sheet2"'s data should also change accordingly.

How could I achieve this?

**Sheet 1**

[image: sheet 1 image link]

**Sheet 2** (empty)

[image: sheet 2 image link]

Answer (score 5):

Try to use Power Query to get the result:

1. Select Range- go to **Data**- select **From Range/Table**- Enter Power Query Editor:
   [image]
2. **Filter** Gender Column- **Close and Load to** New WorkSheet:
   [image]

If you update data in Sheet1 Table, the data in Sheet2 will update after refreshing.

Comment: is there a way to update the information in the filtered view (Sheet 2) and it gets updated in the master data source (Sheet1). I tested in the way you mentioned, but I cannot in the other direction.

Comment: I appreciate that this answer probably answers my question, however I find it very difficult to follow the animations - too fast, no way to pause.  Also does not help someone relying on a screen reader.

Answer (score 2):

*To solve the issue you need to create a **Helper Column in Sheet 1.***

[image]

Formula in Cell `D2` & fill it Down.

`=IF(C2="M",1+MAX($D$1:D1),"")`

Write this Formula in Cell `A2 of Sheet 2` & fill it Right then Down.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),Sheet1!$D:$D,0)),"")
```

**How it works:**

This simple **INDEX & MATCH** combination did the magic & Filters all Rows have Gender `M`.

Where `MATCH(Rows($1:1)`, returns `1` and as soon drag down it completes, `1, 2, 3, 4 , 5` & `6` and so on, and the Formula uses these values to `Match` & `Filter` Rows for `M`.

[image]

**Note:**

1. You can find *New Records* (Red Color) in the *2nd Screen Shot* been *filtered also in Sheet 2*.
2. Formula in Sheet 2 will reflect *modifications in Gender also*.

[image]

3. **Name I's gender** (Filled with Yellow color) been modified, excluded by the formula in Sheet 2.
4. Adjust Cell references in the Formula as needed.

Answer (score 0):

***I've added this answer in regard of New Arrival Dynamic Array Formula, works only with Version 2021 and higher.***

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Convert range A51:C57 into TABLE.
2. Reason is, adding new record expands the data set automatically, and
   if match with the criterion updates the FILTERED records on other
   sheet.
3. Formula used in Sheet 4 cell A3 is,

   =FILTER(Sheet3!$A$51:$C$60,Sheet3!$C$51:$C$60="M","")

**N.B.**

1. The biggest advantage of using this NEW dynamic array formula are,

   A. Spills automatically when SOURCE data receives NEW Records.

   B. Considering the OLD solutions, no need of HELP data.