# How do I dynamically update vlookup table when another lookup value is added?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have a simple (formatted as) table (Table 1), ranked based on Rating.

```
Rank Name Rating
1 etc etc etc 
4 etc etc etc 
3 etc etc etc 
2 etc etc etc
```

I have a VLOOKUP (formatted as) table (Table 2) that looks at the rank for sorting.

Now when I add another value to Table 1, I need to go into Table 2 and add a number that the vlookup, looks for, to expand the table.

Is there a way to make that part automatic?

So when I add a new line to table 1, table 2 to automatically updates.

Comment: Macro is the best method to automate the action,, are you comfortable with Macro,, also please [Edit] your post & for better understanding add some genuine sample data in both Tables.

Comment: [Check this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1389474/microsoft-excel-display-realtime-filtering-data-from-another-worksheet/1389684#1389684) help you to solve the issue.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your Vlookup formula, there are likely several ways to do what you need without PQ or VBA.  It sounds like you are using the lookup to find the rank, and your rank is hardcoded like VLOOKUP(**4**,Table1[Rank],1,0), where **4** is the last rank you added and it will change to **5**.  If that's the case then you can likely take the hardcoded rank out be replacing it with `ROW()-1` then use a dynamic named range with OFFSET and COUNTA to expand your lookup column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FILTER()` is the thing you need:

```
=FILTER(Table1,Table1[Column1]<>"")
```

`Table1` keeps track of its components so adding values adds those values to the things it keeps track of. `FILTER()`, then, returns all its components, including the just added ones.

For the sorting aspect, you may just use `SORT()` on that result.

**There is just one problem...**

`FILTER()` will not work as desired IN a Table. It will happily work ON a Table, from outside it, but not IN one.

Since your output is in a Table as well, you cannot use it in it. So... either it must not be in a Table, or you must eschew array formulas like `FILTER()` (and `SORT()`, which is also indicated here).

So, why must it be in a formal Table? It seems like most of the points of having a Table are not needed for populating it as you describe its population as coming from the method you seek here, not from physical data entry to it (the physical data entry being done in Table1). The rest of the points would be using "structured references" in formulas elsewhere that look to Table2 for input.

Not only are those overrated, and rather verbose, they are not in any way necessary as one can simply, for just one way, Name columns for similar use. So one must decide which is more important:  the easy population AND sorting of the data for visual(?) use in Table2 or use of structured references that refer to Table2?

Another way, which I've used and found no more obnoxious than the old ways before Tables, would be an intermediate "table" using `FILTER()` to populate it, and sort it, then the old ways to build formulas to populate the actual Table2 which will have the automatic sorting applied to it by having it automatically applied to the helper table range. So your Table2 would be fully populated, sorted, and available for follow-on use using structured references.

All the above has difficulties that your true circumstances will show to need overcoming, and some that just won't be an issue in your literal usage.

One point in favor would be that someday Excel will fix the Table vs. Array Formula issue. Well, certainly before 2050. -Ish. Someday. When it does, you can just update by replacing Table2's formulas with `SORT(FILTER())` from the helper table/range and delete the helper table.

Or, as others have mentioned, if VBA is available to you (bosses don't mind using it) and you know how to, VBA would solve it utterly for you.

Comment: I know this is a 3 year old question, but I have been using FIlter for a while now.